# Netbeans Java Library inclusion

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project (P) which uses (my own) library project (L) as a library. Project L includes 3rd party library Apache HTTPClient.

Why does P not function when including L jar unless P separately includes the 3rd party jar that L does?

I thought P would kind of "inherit" any libraries that L had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be good utility but it does not unless you use maven and assembly plugin of maven (for distribution of all jars).

If you just use maven it will work inside the IDE but not without it. To package a stand alone app the target should be a ear file or use the assembly plugin.

I guess the IDE does not do it for you as you can add them youself and that gives you the flexibility to swap versions of popular 3rd party jars and mocking.